# c - pointer as an initializer for an object with static duration

Tags: c, pointers, static, initialization

**I. Background for the question.**

As for 6.7.8., 4) of the Standard:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

As for 6.2.4. 3) of the Standard:

> An  object  whose  identifier  is  declared  with  external  or
> internal  linkage,  or  with  the storage-class  specifier **static**
> has static  storage  duration.

As for 6.6. 7) of the Standard:

> More  latitude  is  permitted  for  constant  expressions  in
> initializers.

and 6.6. 9):

> An address constant is a null pointer,a pointer to an lvalue designating
> an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function
> designator; ...

Finally, in 6.3.2.1. 1) we read:

> An lvalue is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type
> other than void;

**II. Question.**

I have the following declarations in `object.h` :

```
 struct class_check_s {
     char blank;
 };
 struct class_check_s class_check = { 0 };
 struct class_check_s *passed = &class_check;

struct object_vt_s {
    /* ... */
    struct class_check_s *safecheck;
    /* ... */
};
```

`object.h` is `includ`ed into `object.c` , in which i have the following piece of code:

```
struct object_vt_s object_vt = {
    /* ... */
    .safecheck= passed,
    /* ... */
};
```

`gcc` is yelling at `.safecheck= passed` part:

> error: initializer element is not constant

`clang` is similar:

> error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant

But i thought that my situation is falling under 6.6. 9). I guess not? I cannot find the answer why exactly though.

---

What i am doing is kinda a little oop module mostly for studying purposes. I am trying to achieve some sort of a dynamic type checking inside of objects' "methods".

Comment: `passed` is a variable. It happened to be initialized with a compile time constant, but it's still a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What 6.6 9 means by “a pointer to an lvalue…” is a pointer-value for an lvalue, that is, the address of an lvalue. While your `struct class_check_s *passed` is called a “pointer,” it is more specifically an object whose value is a pointer. When you write `.safecheck = passed`, you are not giving the compiler the value it wants for the initializer; you are telling it to get the value from `passed`.

You could write `.safecheck = &class_check`. This initializes `safecheck` to the address of `class_check`, and the compiler is able to describe that address to the linker so that the program loader can correctly adjust its value when the program starts.

However, with `.safecheck = passed`, the compiler nominally has to read the value of `passed` from storage. In theory, a good compiler could look at the initialization of `passed`, see it is initialized to `&class_check`, and use that value for the initialization. The C standard does not formally prohibit this, but it does not require it, and it would be unusual. Additionally, note the semantics here are a bit wonky: `passed` is not declared `const`, so its value could change, so why should any particular value of it be used when `.safecheck = passed` is compiled? Sure, it is all “compile-time” stuff, but that is adding semantics to the C language that are not specified by the C standard. As far as the semantics of C goes, `passed` does not exist (no storage is reserved for it) until program execution starts.

Comment: Aaah, i see now. So, it is basically the same thing why `static int a = b+c` won't work, even if `b` and `c` have static duration also.
As i may understand, `const` does not stand really for constant per se, rather than for immodifiable variable.
Just to be completelly sure - could you advise if a pointer constant is an integer constant in terms of 6.4.4.1.?

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: An object defined with `const`, such as `const int x = 3;` or `char * const p = &foo;`, is not a constant according to the C standard, either in clause 6.4 or 6.6, except that “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions” (C 2018 6.6 10). A compiler might optimize as if it were, though, but that is up to the compiler. Also, C++ has diverged from C in regard to constants. I believe it is accepting more things as compile-time constants than C and supporting more compile-time computations.

Comment: Yep, i guess relying on such a feature of a compiler won't make my programs any portable, so will stick to the word of the Standard. As for C++, as I read that example from my first comment would work in here as like `a + b` was constant expression. But I don't know C++ yet )
Also, could you advise, just to be completely sure, if if a pointer constant is an integer constant in terms of 6.4.4.1.?

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: 6.4.4, including 6.4.4.1, is solely about lexical constants—things in source text that are immediately interpretable as values. For the integers, those constants are what I call “literals”—the value of an integer constant is literally in its text. E.g., `34` has the value 34 and `0x20u` has the value 32 (“20” interpreted as base 16). The rules in 6.4.4 would have no effect on expressions like `&class_check`; that is an expression, not an integer constant. It can be a constant expression for initialization purposes, but it is not an integer constant as defined by 6.4.4.1.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil : thank you for your advises! They were very helpful, now it is much more clear for me for sure!